# Ember. Rerender custom array that is in a component. Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember app that has a template with several dropdown menus(the dropdown menus are in a component.hbs).
Inside the component.js, there is a custom array (ingredients) that takes objects from the model and filters them depending of the selections.
The problem is that the data doesn't refresh automatically for the following selectors, I have to refresh the website to be able to see the next options.

For example: 2 selectors: "recipies" and "ingredients" 
A user selects "meatloaf". The ingredients selector, that would take the data from a custom array in the component, doesn't refresh itself in order to display only the ingredients for meatloaf. 
I'm assuming this is happening because the component.hbs (and the ingredientes array)have been rendered and loaded when the user visits the website, but I need to find a way to refresh the ingredients array everytime a user selects a recipe

Answer (score 0):

Define computed property in the component, which will be recalculated whenever `selectedRecipe` changes.

```
ingredients:Ember.computed('selectedRecipe', function(){
 // do filtering stuff and return the result
 return this.get('customArray').filterBy('name',this.get('selectedRecipe'));
})
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the setupController code?

Comment: Something like this?:
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    Ember.set(model,'ingredient', ingredientArray);
    Ember.set(model,'price',pricesArray);
  },

Comment: Should the array be defined in the controller to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

So, I just figured it out.
It was way more simple than I thought. 
In the same action that is triggered when the user selects a recipe, I empty the array for ingredients, and then fill it out with what the ingredients related to the selection.